# UITableView delegate/datasource default value

Tags: ios, uitableview

Simple question. I noticed that when I subclass UITableViewController, it's UITableView automatically sets it's delegate/datasource to my class. Do I need to set the tableview delegate/datasource manually to my class just for code correctness or is that the expected behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is the official expected behavior.

This is detailed [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in the documentation, especially in the paragraph "Overview":

> **Overview**
>
> *The UITableViewController class creates a controller object that manages a table view. It implements the following behavior:*
>
> - [...]
> - If a nib file containing the table view is loaded, the data source and delegate become those objects defined in the nib file (if any). If no nib file is specified or **if the nib file defines no data source or delegate, `UITableViewController` sets the data source and the delegate of the table view to self**.

Comment: Nice, I swear I tried to find it on the docs but couldn't. Thank you!

Comment: It looks like it's no longer the case. At least for .dataSource. It's set to _UIFilteredDataSource for some reason. You can take a look at [this playground](https://imgur.com/a/asmZN6K)

Answer (score 2):

in a UITableViewController, the delegate and datasource of the UITableView created by the ViewController is the ViewController by default.

If you create your own UITableView then you have to assign the datasource and delegate yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes..it will automatically set the delegates methods. as it is doing that internally.
It does in case of coding implenmentation

As the documentation says :

```
 @interface UITableViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

So, it is internally setting the delegate methods.

Comment: Errr... The fact that `UITableViewController` conforms to those protocols does not mean at all that the `delegate` and `dataSource` properties of the `tableView` are automatically associated to the `UITableViewController`!

Comment: I agree, but I was just saying that the line you are quoting from the Class Reference does not "proves" anything at all, we could have that protocol conformance and still not this behavior ;)